# Convert 24-Hour format datetime to varchar Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem in converting sql server 2008 datetime to varchar,

```
Select convert(varchar(20),convert(datetime, '2013-12-11 00:59:00.000'))
```

the result is `Dec 11 2013 12:59AM` but I need it to be actually `Dec 11 2013 00:59AM` as in the database dates are of 24-Hour format.

How can I correct the query?

Comment: If you have `00:59` what purpose does the AM serve? If you want the clock to be 24 hour, specifying AM/PM seems kind of redundant to me.

Comment: In most well designed systems, you can avoid every processing datetimes as anything *other* than datetime values on the database side of things. This type of formatting usually belongs a long way away from the database.

Comment: Database is made to store data, not to format datetimes into strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions, cast and convert that you can use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

You forgot to put in the format style.

```
-- Using cast
Select cast('2013-12-11 00:59:00.000' as varchar(20)) as my_casted_date

-- Using convert
Select convert(varchar(24), '2013-12-11 00:59:00.000', 113) as my_converted_date
```

[image]

Use format with custom date time strings for utlitmate flexibility.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

```
-- Using format
DECLARE @my_date datetime2 = '2013-12-11 00:59:00.000';
SELECT format(@my_date, 'MMM dd yyyy HH:MM tt', 'en-us') as str_english_date
```

[image]

Solution that will work with SQL Server 2008.

```
-- Create a date time variable
DECLARE @my_date DATETIME2 = '2013-12-11 00:59:00.000';

-- Using convert
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(24),  @my_date, 113) +
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(HH, @my_date) < 12 THEN ' AM'
    ELSE ' PM'
    END
AS my_converted_date;
```

Comment: I need the answer must be like this "Dec 11 2013 00:59AM"

Comment: Format() function is only available in SQL Server 2008R2 and 2012

Comment: @Jade: actually, `FORMAT` is only available in SQL Server **2012** - not in 2008 R2 ...

Comment: Yes you're correct, just made some mistake including MSSQL 2008R2.

Comment: Jade - I included the link.  I find most people want to be spoon feed on this site.  Some research is necessary by the person asking the question.  Otherwise, they will not learn.

Answer (score 1):

This will be perfect for you..

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt='12-Jan-2014 23:59'

SELECT Right(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dt, 100),7) AS DateTime_In_12h_Format
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not nice but it does its job:

```
DECLARE @Var DATETIME;
SET @Var = '2013-12-11T00:59:00.000';
SELECT 
    @Var AS SourceValue, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Var, 100) AS FormatedValue1,
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Var, 100) LIKE '%[ ]12:__AM' THEN REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Var, 100), ' 12:', ' 00:')
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Var, 100)
    END AS FormatedValue2

SourceValue             FormatedValue1      FormatedValue2
----------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2013-12-11 00:59:00.000 Dec 11 2013 12:59AM Dec 11 2013 00:59AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Select convert(varchar(20),convert(datetime, '2013-12-11 00:59:00.000'),113) + ' ' +RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), Convert(datetime,'2013-12-11 00:59:00.000'), 109), 2)
```

Output

```
11 Dec 2013 00:59:00 AM
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12667)